# What are some early exemplars of thought experiments in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: vedas, meditation

A category of experiments called [Thought Experiments](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/thought-experiment/) are considered doyens among the pillars that support and exemplify process of Enquiry. Some of the examples include [Schrodinger's Cat in a box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), [Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise), [Einstein's Chasing a beam of light](http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/papers/Chasing_final.pdf) and some lesser known ones such as [Maxwell's Demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon), [Brain-in-a-vat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat), [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) and [Prisoner's Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma).

This leads to the obvious question: What are some of the exemplars of specific thought experiments that have been devised historically **within Hinduism** that unequivocally reveal and/or justify specific ideas of Vedas?

Comment: Your question, as currently posed is rather unclear, and it could also lead to a lot of opinion-based speculation.  First of all, I don't think any of the thought experiments you listed involve the scientific method, except perhaps in some extremely metaphorical sense that you understand and I don't.  And second of all, the way your title is worded could lead people to think that you're looking for the scientific accomplishments of Hinduism, which could lead to a lot of speculation.

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking a simple question like "What thought experiments are found in Hindu scripture?" or something, without all the baggage involving psychonauts, the scientific method, higher states of consciousness, etc.

Comment: Or, if you're not actually interested in Ship of Theseus-style of thought experiments, but instead want to know about meditations that lead to higher state of consciousness, then you can ask about that.  For instance the Brahma Sutras describe how meditating upon the 32 Brahmavidyas leads to Brahmajnana which leads to Moksha.  And the Yoga Sutras describe how various kinds of meditation lead to different kinds of Siddhis or magical powers.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks, I have rephrased my question.

Comment: OK, it's still not perfectly clear to me, but it's good enough to reopen.

Comment: In any case, would a Brahmavidya qualify as an answer to your question? A Brahmavidya basically takes the form "Here is a true fact about Brahman given in the Upanishads.  Meditate upon this fact in order to attain knowledge of Brahman."  That doesn't really have much connection to thought experiments like the Ship of Theseus.  A thought experiment is something of the form "Here is a scenario X which is not true.  But imagine if X were true.  Then it would imply Y.  So that has implications concerning Z."  I don't know of anything of that form in either Hindu scriptures or works of Acharyas.

Comment: Now I do know of analogies, parables, and allegories used in Hinduism to illustrate a point or make an argument.  But that strikes me as different than a thought experiment, and it also has nothing to do with repeated meditation.  (But then again I don't think thought experiments have anything to do with repeated meditation either.)  Also, in Hindu philosophical works there is proof by contradiction, where you suppose your opponent is right and derive a contradiction, but that too is different from a thought experiment and different from the object of repeated meditation.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks, i've further cut the fat so as to bring out what i want.